# How do I create a DOM tree from an XML file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xml, dom

Can someone give me a direction as how I can create a DOM tree from an XML file in C#/WPF, if any one has had any experience with this, maybe what classes you've used? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why you wanna work with DOM? It's old technology and may be later you have problems for support,..., Also It's slower than newer technologies like XDocument, Also it's really not easy, e.g creating tree is easy but update and search is not easy.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `XmlDocument` class for loading your XML File into a DOM.

> **MSDN** - This class implements the W3C Document Object Model (DOM) Level 1 Core and the Core DOM Level 2. The DOM is an in-memory (cache) tree representation of an XML document and enables the navigation and editing of this document. Because XmlDocument implements the IXPathNavigable interface it can also be used as the source document for the XslTransform class.

#### More Information

- [MSDN - XmlDocument Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)
- [Working with Xml DOM](http://www.mastercsharp.com/Article/69/working-with-xml-dom)

Answer (score 2):

[LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) works great for this; I find it much easier to use than the DOM. Try:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("PurchaseOrder.xml");
Console.WriteLine(doc);
```

Comment: +1 I want write this, but I see you wrote it:), Also DOM is slower and takes more memory than XDocument.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `XmlDocument` (`System.Xml`) class or the `XDocument` (`System.Xml.Linq`) class.